Click button change the css in php and ajax
I am struggling to use Ajax so I tried to just use Javascript without it. I want to create a button switch on a banner so I can change the style of the page between 2 css files already created. I had already a form in another php file so I can chose the style and then submit it so it can change the style in all the plugin. I am thinking about getting the option with a post
This is my form :
/**
 * Class used to manage the display of the content of the settings
 */
class WoosterPartnerSettings
{
    /**
     * Hook to display the contents of the 'Settings' menu if the license is valid
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (get_option('partner_license') && get_option('partner_license') != '') {
            add_action('tab_content_settings', array($this, 'wooster_partner_settings'));
            add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'display_style'));
            add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_style'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Allows you to display the form to choose the style sheet to display
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function wooster_partner_settings()
    {
?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1><?php echo __('Réglages Wooster', 'wooster-partner'); ?></h1>
            <hr class="line">

            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php settings_fields('wooster-settings-group'); ?>
                <?php do_settings_sections('wooster-settings-group'); ?>

                <p class="parag"><?php echo __('Le plugin Compagnon propose deux styles d’affichage :', 'wooster-partner'); ?></p>

                <label for="style_wordpress">
                    <input type="radio" id="style_wordpress" name="wooster_style" value="compagnon-wp.css" <?php checked(get_option('wooster_style'), 'compagnon-wp.css'); ?>>
                    <?php echo __('Style WordPress', 'wooster-partner'); ?>
                </label>

                <label for="style_wooster">
                    <input type="radio" id="style_wooster" name="wooster_style" value="compagnon-wooster.css" <?php checked(get_option('wooster_style'), 'compagnon-wooster.css'); ?>>
                    <?php echo __('Style Wooster', 'wooster-partner'); ?>
                </label><br>

                <input type="submit" class="wooster-button" value="<?php echo __('Enregistrer les modifications', 'wooster-partner') ?>">
            </form>
        </div>
<?php
    }


    /**
     * Registers the setting for the Wooster plugin style
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function display_style()
    {
        register_setting('wooster-settings-group', 'wooster_style');
    }

    /**
     * Enqueues the selected style for Wooster plugin settings page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function enqueue_style()
    {
        if (is_admin()) {
            if (isset($_GET['page']) && strpos($_GET['page'], 'wooster') === 0) {
                $selected_style = get_option('wooster_style', 'compagnon-wp.css'); // default style
                wp_enqueue_style('wooster-custom-style', plugins_url('wooster-partner/assets/css/' . $selected_style));
            }
        }
    }
    }
new WoosterPartnerSettings();

and this is my banner I created so it can be in all the plugin :
if (!class_exists('WoosterBanner')) {
    class WoosterBanner
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            if (isset($_GET['page']) && in_array($_GET['page'], ['wooster','wooster-followup','wooster-licences','wooster-compagnon','wooster-customers','wooster-partner','wooster-settings','wooster-setup']) && is_admin()) {
                add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_styles'));
                add_action('in_admin_header', array($this, 'wooster_header_section'));
                 add_action('wp_ajax_switch_css', array($this, 'switch_css')); // request when the user is logged in
            }
        }

        public function wooster_header_section() {
            ?>
            <div id="top-bar-banner">
            <div class="wooster-banner">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="<?php echo plugins_url('assets/img/logo.avif', __DIR__); ?>" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <form method="post" action="options.php" id="form">
            <?php settings_fields('wooster-settings-group'); ?>
            <button type="button" id="wooster-exchange-button" class="button">
                <i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
        <a href="#" class="button"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
        }



        public function switch_css() {

            // Check the request
            $style = isset($_POST['style']) ? $_POST['style'] : '';
            // style is the id of the selected style in the html and the button
            if ($style === 'wooster-custom-style-css') {
                //set cookie to remember the selected style
                setcookie('selected_style', $style, time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
                echo plugins_url('assets/css/compagnon-wooster.css', __FILE__);
            } elseif ($style === 'csspartner-css') {
                //set cookie to remember the selected style
                setcookie('selected_style', $style, time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
                echo plugins_url('assets/css/compagnon-wp.css', __FILE__);
            }

            // Don't forget to exit at the end of the function
            exit;
        }

        public function enqueue_styles() {
            // Register necessary styles and scripts
            wp_enqueue_style('wooster-banner', plugins_url('assets/css/banner.css', __DIR__));
            wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css', array(), '5.15.4');

            wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // Js library
            wp_enqueue_script('wooster-banner', plugins_url('assets/js/banner.js', __DIR__), array('jquery'), null, true);


        }
    }
    new WoosterBanner();

}

    var currentStyle = 'style_wordpress'; // Définissez le style par défaut ici

    document.getElementById("wooster-exchange-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var style1 = document.getElementById('style_wordpress');
        var style2 = document.getElementById('style_wooster');

        if (currentStyle === 'style_wordpress') {
            style1.disabled = true;
            style2.disabled = false;
            currentStyle = 'style_wooster';
        } else {
            style1.disabled = false;
            style2.disabled = true;
            currentStyle = 'style_wordpress';
        }
    });
});
 ``


There are not buttons in PHP. PHP is the program that generates the page source(s), and it literally dies after sending that to the browser. A button changing which CSS is active is a purely client-side CSS+JS question and the usual way you make that happen is that you set a class on whatever is the highest parent element, and any CSS that needs to kick in then has that class name at the start of each of its rules. Or in modern nested CSS, wraps your rules.

I am using wordpress. I don't want the button to change just call the css file when I click on it . It will change between 2 files each time I click

It's CSS: they're tiny files (because it's plain text and the server sends them compressed) and they get cached by the browser after first load. Load all the CSS you might need, with each file having appropriate class prefixes, and then toggle away? Alternatively, but definitely worse, make your JS either change your current stylesheet href, or append a new link element to the head, so the browser can do the rest.

This is what I tried to do but when I change the setting from the form above, it only works when Wooster style is chose. The method is not call. I have to call the method in button click
 <?php
/**
 * WoosterBanner class
 * It creates  a banner for the Wooster plugin
 *
 * @package Wooster
 */
class WoosterBanner
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['page']) && in_array($_GET['page'], ['wooster','wooster-followup','wooster-licences','wooster-compagnon','wooster-customers','wooster-partner','wooster-settings','wooster-setup']) && is_admin()) {
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_styles'));
        add_action('in_admin_header', array($this, 'wooster_header_section'));
        add_action('admin_footer', array($this, 'add_switch_style_button'));
        }
    }
    /**
     * Adds the banner to the top of the Wooster plugin settings page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function wooster_header_section()
    {
        ?>
        <div id="top-bar-banner">
            <div class="wooster-banner">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="<?php echo plugins_url('assets/img/logo.avif', __DIR__); ?>" alt="Logo">
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                <a class="button"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a>
                <a class="button" id="switch-style"><i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i></a>
                <a class="button"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    /**
     * Registers the setting for the Wooster plugin style switch button
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function add_switch_style_button()
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            // The switch button is retrieved by its id
            var switchButton = document.getElementById('switch-style');
            // Ids of the stylesheets to switch between
            var currentStylesheetId = 'csspartner-css';
            var otherStylesheetId = 'wooster-custom-style-css';
            // When the switch button is clicked, the current stylesheet is disabled and the other one is enabled
            switchButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                var currentStylesheet = document.getElementById(currentStylesheetId);
                var otherStylesheet = document.getElementById(otherStylesheetId);
            // If the stylesheets exist, they are switched
                if (currentStylesheet && otherStylesheet) {
                    currentStylesheet.disabled = !currentStylesheet.disabled;
                    otherStylesheet.disabled = !otherStylesheet.disabled;
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php
}

    /**
     * Enqueues the selected style for Wooster plugin settings page
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function enqueue_styles()
    {
        wp_enqueue_style('wooster-banner', plugins_url('assets/css/banner.css', __DIR__));
        wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css', array(), '5.15.4');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // Js library
        wp_localize_script('switch-style', 'switch_style_vars', array(
            'wooster_style_url' => plugins_url("wooster-partner/assets/css/compagnon-wooster.css"),
            'wp_style_url' => plugins_url("wooster-partner/assets/css/compagnon-wp.css"),
        ));
    }
}

new WoosterBanner();

